# Joomla: find current module/plugin path

Tags: php, url, joomla, joomla3.4

I am currently developing my first own Joomla content plugin.
I'd like to add own CSS to the document object, so I need the path of my plugin.

Of course I can do use something like

```
$styleSheet = JURI::base(). "plugins/content/<my plugin>/css/mystyle.css
```

But I'd like to also use some API to find my actual installation path.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only API call for adding stylesheets is

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet('path/to/style.css');
```

You can use the JURI::base() - function to get an absolute path, but it is not necessary.

There is no API-calls for getting the url-path to a plugin or a module, as it it not really needed, the plugin or module are not called directly by this uri anyway.

It is common practice to place style-elements, javascripts etc for plugins, modules and components in the /media-folder. Explore this folder to see how  it is done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!